# How to find the values of trigonometrical functions for any angle in radians

Tags: trigonometry

In order to find the values of trigonometrical functions for any angle in terms of those of positive acute angle, we have the following algorithm (from my textbook):

> ALGORITHM
>
> STEP I: See whether the given angle a is positive or negative if it is negative, make it positive by using the following:
> $$\sin(-θ) = -\sin θ,\ \cos(-θ) = \cos θ,\ \tan(-θ)= -\tan θ,\ \text{etc.}$$
> STEP II: Express the positive angle a obtained in step I in the form $α=90°n ± θ$, where $θ$ is an acute angle.
> STEP III: Determine the quadrant in which the terminal side of the angle $α$ lies.
> STEP IV: Determine the sign of the given trigonometrical function in the quadrant obtained in step III.
> STEP V: If $n$ in step II is an odd integer, then
> \begin{gather*}
> \sin α =±\cos θ,\ \cos α =±\sin θ,\ \tan α =±\cot θ,\\
> \sec α = ±\csc θ,\ \csc α = ±\sec θ.
> \end{gather*}
> And the sign on RHS will be the sign obtained in step IV. If $n$ in step II is an even integer, then
> \begin{gather*}
> \sin α=±\sin θ,\ \cos α =±\cos θ,\ \tan α = ±\tan θ,\\
> \sec α= ±\sec θ, \ \csc α = ±\csc θ.
> \end{gather*}
> And the sign on RHS is the sign obtained in step IV.

I am not able to proceed through step II & III, V. If the angle is given in degrees, then I can apply Euclid's division algorithm to express $α=90°n ± θ$, e.g. $590°= 90° × 6 + 30°$. But I am having difficulty if the angle is given in radians (for example $\dfrac{11π}{8}$). Of course I can convert it to degrees but I don't want to.

In step III, how to determine the quadrant in which an angle lies? I am not able to determine the quadrant especially if the angle is very large. Once I know the quadrant I can easily determine the sign by using All Students Take Calculus mnemonic.

So how to find the value of any trigonometric function at any angle in radians and/or degrees? And if you know any tricks for evaluating trigonometrical values then please share it (with an example). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple

Based on your question,I think you have a problem regarding two things

1. You are able to simplify if the angles are in degrees but you are getting stuck in which quadrant should I place the angle

2)Of the angles are in radians you are not able to solve them

So,

For problem 1)

Suppose an angle like 570°
What you did was correct applying Euclid division algorithm

So it would be $570°=90*6+ 30°$

That implies angle(radians) is $(\frac{6\pi}{2} + 30°)$

Upon simplification,$(3\pi +30°)$

What I used to do to remember the quadrants

If the given radian is like $(n\pi)$

Then if $n$ is even then the it is in $+^{ve} $x direction

If $n$ is odd then it is in $-^{ve}$ x direction

Further explanation on how to solve:

If the given angle is like $(n\pi + 30°)$ where 'n' is odd

Then the angle would be $3^{rd}$ quadrant because there is an increase of 30° from $-^{ve} $ x-direction

If it is $(n\pi -30°)$ where n is odd then the angle would lie in $2^{nd}$ quadrant

So similarly if angle is like $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ where n is odd then it there will be two cases

1)Where n is in the form $(4x+1)$ Then it lies in $+^{ve} $ y direction $(x\geq 0)$

For example:$[4(0)+1][\frac{\pi}{2}]$
Then it is $\frac{\pi}{2}$

2)Where n is of the form $(4x-1)$ Then it lies in $-^{ve}$ y direction where $(x\geq 1)$

For example :$(\frac{3\pi}{2})$

Use the same principle as stated for the $n\pi$  logic

This will be enough to solve all the questions related to this

If my answer is not clear,
Then tell me where you need clarity.

For your $2^{nd}$ problem it is pretty simple

In you question you have given $\frac{11\pi}{8}$

The main motive to simplify is to solve trigonometric functions right

So we can apply half angle formula for the given function

Suppose the function is
$ \sin(\frac{11\pi}{8}$

Then we can just simplify through half angle formula that is

$\sin(A) = 2\sin(\frac{A}{2})\cos(\frac{A}{2})$

But if the angle is given as $\frac{613\pi}{2}+\theta$

Then divide 613 by 4 and the
Remainder will determine how to simplify

Two cases:

1)If remainder is 1 then it lies in $-^{ve}$ y direction

2)If remainder is 3 then it lies in $+^{ve} $ y direction

Then I think you can solve through previous mentioned methods but anyway I will solve

$\frac{613\pi}{2}+\theta$

First thing divide 613 by 4

Remainder you will get is 1

So the angle lies in $-^{ve}$ y direction

As it lies in $-^{ve}$ y direction  adding some angle $\theta$ will result in the function being in $4^{th}$ quadrant

If the question is $\sin(\frac{613\pi}{2}+\theta)$

Then as $\frac{613\pi}{2}+\theta)$ lies in $4^{th}$ quadrant

The whole function will change into $-\cos(\theta)$